# Change file location of id="root" for React + Nodejs / Express

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have an **html landing page** I'd like users to land on the they type in my website. The only problem is when I name it `index.html`, react breaks.

putting a `id="root"`  in my landing page just causes react to load all of its components and it gets really messy.

I've tried **renaming** the original index.html:

```
index.html <== Vanilla HTML landing page

react.html <== React/Bundle
```

Then in `server.js` I have the following code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

app.use('*', function(req, resp) {
    resp.sendFile('./client/public/react.html');
  });
```

In its current state, react breaks and I get the error:
"Target container is not a DOM element."

Comment: Where is your code, so far? your complete code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the script tag in your index.html that is referencing your bundle.js.

Add that script tag to your react.html.